# What is the right way to say 'you are welcome X hell' ?

Tags: sentence-construction, prepositions

What is the right way to say:

> You are welcome **to** hell

or

> You are welcome **in** hell

?

p.s I argued with a friend about that.

Comment: Neither one is a recognized expression in English. Is this a literal translation of an idiom from another language? Can you give an example of how it would be used?

Comment: As phenry says, we need more information here. We need to know what you *want* to say in order to give you the correct answer. Either of the currently posted answers could be correct under different circumstances.

Comment: Without clarification from OP regarding what he actually *wants* to say, and in what context, this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My humble opinion:

"Welcome to hell" if you want to taunt or intimidate a person, or just make a kind of a rough joke.

"You are welcomed in hell" if you want to say that you will treat the person nicely in hell; a strange option. (0:

Comment: Yes, wanna say first case. But I finded 300k record about 'Welcome IN hell' in google. Is it mistakes?

Comment: IMHO "Welcome in hell" also sounds OK but without "You are".

Comment: @Mediator You can't search for a short string like that and assume it's correct on its own because you get a lot of results. "Welcome in hell" by itself doesn't mean anything. But google can be giving you results for sentences like "I wonder if prayers would be *welcome in hell*", which is perfectly acceptable. So google isn't always the right answer. If your goal is to tell a person you're angry with that you want them to be in hell, use phenry's *Go to hell!*. If you're commiserating and you think both of you are in a hellish situation, "Welcome to hell" can be a joke as CopperKettle says.

Comment: @Mediator You should've used quotes around the words (100k hits) and realized that those numbers mean bupkis. Clicking over a few pages shows Google only has about 150 actual results. Many are ESL mistakes; the rest are things like "He's so terrible that he's not even welcome in Hell", "Hades tried to make Persephone feel welcome in Hell", or "anyone is welcome in Hell".

Comment: *You're welcome in hell* is grammatical (and there's no need for *welcom**ed***), but wouldn't normally be used to mean "Welcome to hell!" or "Go to hell!"; it simply means someone is welcome in the place called hell. *Welcome in hell!* is ungrammatical; use *Welcome to hell!* instead.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, neither one is a recognized expression in English, and I'm not sure what it's supposed to mean.

If it's intended as a curse, or an expression of anger or ill will, the English equivalent would be **"Go to hell!"**